# Does passport.js allow users to remove accounts? is there an alternative?

Tags: passport.js

I was wondering if passport.js has a method of being able to delete user accounts from an application? If a user decides they no longer want to be registered on my site and wish to remove their account, there should be a way do this? If passport doesn't allow a solution then is there a similar solution?

I am currently at a loss at finding passport.js' answer to this; I assumed it would be a standard operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passport is just an authentication framework, not a user management tool. You will need to implement the account removal yourself.

Assuming you're using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) strategy that is used when the user accounts are on your applications database you will need to

- Implement an API that receives user information and creates a corresponding entry to your database.
- Add a login API that uses Passport. In your verify callback you check if the login user exists, and if their password matches against the values in your database.
- Implement an API that allows logged in users to delete their accounts. In this API you just delete the corresponding entry from your database.

Sometimes you see applications that kinda use Passport for registration. It is not really intended for this, but this way users are logged in after registration. With separate registration the user needs to login manually after registration.